# append() element to a specific dimension of array

Tags: python, python-3.x

The question is actually pretty simply, just look at the code:

```
In [1]: collection = [[]] * 4

In [2]: collection
Out[2]: [[], [], [], []]

In [3]: collection[0].append(1)

In [4]: collection
Out[4]: [[1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

Why append `1` to `collection[0]` also append it to all the other dimensions?
If that's not the correct way to add element into a specific dimension, then what's the right way?

Comment: >>> collection = [[] for i in range(4)]
>>> collection
[[], [], [], []]
>>> collection[0].append(1)
>>> collection
[[1], [], [], []]

Comment: @Fred Awesome!! I began to understand, is it because all these dimensions I wrote share the same memory as i just duplicate them?

Comment: @AmarthGûl you can try "id(collection[0])"  "id(collection[1])".They point to the same element.

Comment: `In [1]: col = [[]] * 4

In [2]: id(col[0])
Out[2]: 1973526363976

In [3]: id(col[1])
Out[3]: 1973526363976` They did... thank you!